# API to create cookie for FireFox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I want to write an application which will create cookies for firefox.
I want to create Client cookies so that firefox will send cookie content in HTTP request.
Similar to the win32 API InternetSetCookie()

Can you please guide on this ?

If you can point me to some code snippet or help, I will try to figure out from that.

This cookie needs to go to SQLITE database, but it seems from old questions that this database get locked if firefox is running. This locking is done in FF 3.5

Just want to confirm if this is the case with FF9 or do we have any API ?

Regards

Comment: Could you provide some context? Why does this have to work in FF only?
Generally speaking, cookies are the web-application's job, so you could either program the server to store a cookie on the client or do some client-side scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Firefox, you can write an add-on to achieve that. Take a look at the source code of the following add-ons. They provide features such as adding, deleting, editing cookies while Firefox is running. It seems they all work with Firefox 9.0.1 (latest stable).

1. [Cookie Manager+](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-manager-plus/)
2. [Advanced Cookie Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-manager/)
3. [Add N Edit Cookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-n-edit-cookies/)
4. [Edit Cookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/edit-cookies/)

**Edit:**

I am posting some cookie management code from the Evernote plugin's *MozillaCookieManagerImpl.js* file. I think the code speaks for itself. Have a look below. It shows how to access cookies, set, get and remove them etc.

**Accessing Mozilla's Cookie Management Interface**

```
Evernote.MozillaCookieManagerImpl = function MozillaCookieManagerImpl() {
};
Evernote.inherit(Evernote.MozillaCookieManagerImpl,
    Evernote.CookieManagerImpl, true);
Evernote.MozillaCookieManagerImpl.isResponsibleFor = function(navigator) {
  var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  return (ua.indexOf("firefox") >= 0 || ua.indexOf("thunderbird") >= 0 || ua
      .indexOf("shredder") >= 0);
};


Evernote.MozillaCookieManagerImpl.prototype.manager = null;
Evernote.MozillaCookieManagerImpl.prototype._ios = null;
Evernote.MozillaCookieManagerImpl.prototype._cookieSrv = null;
Evernote.MozillaCookieManagerImpl.prototype._cookieManagerSrv = null;


Evernote.MozillaCookieManagerImpl.prototype.getIOService = function() {
  if (this._ios == null) {
    this._ios = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
  }
  return this._ios;
};


Evernote.MozillaCookieManagerImpl.prototype.getCookieService = function(
    force) {
  if (this._cookieSrv == null || force) {
    this._cookieSrv = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookieService;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieService);
  }
  return this._cookieSrv;
};


Evernote.MozillaCookieManagerImpl.prototype.getCookieManagerService = function(
    force) {
  if (this._cookieManagerSrv == null || force) {
    this._cookieManagerSrv = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieManager);
  }
  return this._cookieManagerSrv;
};
```

**Get Cookie**

```
Evernote.MozillaCookieManagerImpl.prototype.get = function(name, url) {
  var uri = this.getIOService().newURI(url, null, null);
  var cookieMgr = this.getCookieManagerService();
  if (cookieMgr) {
    for ( var e = cookieMgr.enumerator; e.hasMoreElements();) {
      var cookie = e.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsICookie);
      if (cookie && cookie.host == uri.host && cookie.name == name) {
        return new Evernote.Cookie(cookie);
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```

**Set Cookie**

```
Evernote.MozillaCookieManagerImpl.prototype.set = function(cookie, url) {
  var uri = (typeof url == 'string') ? this.getIOService().newURI(url, null,
      null) : null;
  if (cookie instanceof Evernote.Cookie && typeof cookie.name == 'string'
      && cookie.name.length > 0) {
    this.getCookieService().setCookieString(uri, null,
        (cookie.name + "=" + cookie.value + ";"), null);
  }
};
```

**Removie Cookie**

```
Evernote.MozillaCookieManagerImpl.prototype.remove = function(name, url) {
  var cookieMgr = this.getCookieManagerService();
  var urlParts = url.split("://", 2);
  var domain = (urlParts.length == 2) ? urlParts[1] : urlParts[0];
  urlParts = domain.split("/", 2);
  var path = (urlParts.length == 2) ? urlParts[1] : null;
  cookieMgr.remove(domain, name, path, false);
};
```

Comment: i am now looking for doing this using nsICookiemanager in Mozilla SDk